# Remove default blank option ----- with blank=True

Tags: django, django-forms

Im using Django to create a form.
The form includes a `models.SmallIntegerField`.

The field has a default blank option (displayed as "------").

**How can I get rid of this blank option?**

Please note that the field is not required (blank=True), therefore the `default=None, blank=False` solution does not work in my case.

Comment: Why do you wanna remove the blank option if the field is not required?

Comment: Because the user can select a "data not available" checkbox, and if its checked then the field is not required. If not checked, the field is required.

Comment: And because I use the RadioSelect widget, so it looks odd with the "----" field.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution myself: Its hacky and ugly, but it works.

Feel free to comment or post another answer if you got a better solution.

```
class myModelForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choose'].choices = self.fields['choose'].choices[1:]

    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        widgets = {
            'choose': RadioSelect(),
        }
```

Comment: Another option would be to subclass the widget and have it load a js file that always removes the first option. Don't think that's better though.

Comment: That would probably work, but it sounds like the hack is equally ugly ;-)